# Can we find $t₂∈(0,1)$ such that $f(α+t₂(μ-α),β+t₂(ρ-β))≠0$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:ℝ²→ℝ$ be an arbitrary non-zero harmonic function. Assume that there exists $t₁∈(0,1)$ such that $f(α+t₁(μ-α),β+t₁(ρ-β))=0$. Then my **question** is: Can we find $t₂∈(0,1)$ such that $t₂≠t₁$ and $f(α+t₂(μ-α),β+t₂(ρ-β))≠0$. Here $α,μ,β,ρ$ are constants.

Comment: If $f\equiv 0$, surely not.

Comment: @TooOldForMath: Yes I mean non-zero harmonic function.

Comment: @TooOldForMath: Thank you for your answer. I require only the function vanishes on a single point $(α+t₂(μ−α),β+t₂(ρ−β))$ not in a full line.

Comment: Lol. Yes, but if it vanishes on the entire line, it vanishes *in particular* at a single point. The thing is that you can *not* find your $t_2$ such that $f(..)\not=0$. That means *exactly* that $f$ is zero on the full line (segment).

Comment: @TooOldForMath: This result then valid for only harmnic function

Comment: Its valid for every class of functions which includes the example $f(x,y)=x$ and allows for rotations and translations.

Comment: @TooOldForMath: Can you elaborate about your technique of rotations and translations to get that function vanish on the full line.

Comment: Well a translation is a map $\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}$, $(x,y)\mapsto (x+a,y+b)$ and a rotation (say with the angle $\phi$) is of the form $(x,y)\mapsto (\cos(\phi)x, \sin(\phi)y)$. Say your line has angle $\phi$ with the line $\{x=0\}$ then you just rotate it back by that angle. Then it is parallel to $\{x=0\}$. Now translate it by $(-\alpha,-\beta)$.

Comment: @TooOldForMath: By these considerations, every continuous function satisfy that property.

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: @TooOldForMath: Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **no**.

Your question asks whether harmonic functions can be $0$ on lines without identically vanishing.

Yes, they can: $f(x,y)=x$ is harmonic and vanishes on the line $\{x=0\}$.

Now we can rotate and translate to make that function vanish on the line to which your line segment $\{(\alpha+t(\mu-\alpha),\beta+t(\rho-\beta))\,:\,t\in(0,1)\}$ belongs.